# read a property from .properties-file with JavaFX

Tags: properties, javafx

So I have my .properties-file named prop.properties with this property.

default = google.com

Now I have a textfield called txtfld in my fxml-file.

Is it possible to set the default-property's value as the value of this textfield without using the initialize-method in the controller/companion ?
I mean, can you do this in the fxml-file itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `Properties` to the [`FXMLLoader` (as constructor argument)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) and use the `%` sign to use values from the properties file:

```
<TextField fx:id="txtfld" text="%default" />
```